# How to link mysql in dev c++?

Tags: c++, mysql, windows

I just downloaded http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=414392 and set include/bin/lib folders to my compiler(tdm-gcc 4.8.1) in dev c++.

I can use functions from mysql.h (#include )

But i cant compile program.
bcoz:

```
undefined reference to `mysql_init'
undefined reference to `mysql_select_db'
```

what i have to do?

Comment: Explain how you are compiling your code. What is the compilation command?

Comment: it is windows 7 i only press f9 :D But i think it is: 
`code
Kompilator: TDM-GCC 4.8.1
Building Makefile "D:\programowanie\dev-c++\Makefile.win"
Wykonywanie  make...
mingw32-make.exe -f "D:\programowanie\dev-c++\Makefile.win" all
g++.exe project1_win/main.o project1_win/class_irc.o project1_win/class_mysql.o -o Projekt1_win.exe -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib" -L"D:/Program Files (x86)/migw/mysql2/lib" -lws2_32 -mwindows -g3

project1_win/class_mysql.o:`

Comment: Make sure all the `*.o` files go in front of other compilation arguments. Order of arguments to `g++.exe` program matters a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the '-L' arguments including the lib directories, but you don't appear to have a '-l' argument linking the actual library. I think what you want to add is '-lmysqlclient' or something similar. Please see the following page for more information:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-building-clients.html

Comment: `Warning .drectve /DEFAULTLIB:"LIBCMT" /DEFAULTLIB:"OLDNAMES" ' unrecognized`

for
`-lmysqlclient`

Comment: Those looks like MSVC arguments; was part of your program, or any of your libraries, compiled with Visual Studio? You should make sure you're using MingW versions of all libraries and not Visual Studio versions...

Comment: i try with -lmysql -- compile fine but when i run program:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/692/t9qs.png/

Comment: ` MYSQL * myData ;
    if ( (myData = mysql_init((MYSQL*) 0)))`

If i comment 'if' line (second) program starts ok. I dont understand...